# when I click right lightbox arrow highlight appears?

Tags: css, selection

Here is a link to a page on my website below:

http://top-drawer.net/artist-1.html

On the page your see some thumbnails with a bigger image next to them. Click the bigger picture and it will reveal a lightbox.

Now my problem is this. When I click the right arrow button on my lightbox to cycle to the next image a highlight appears below the image. Press quite quickly to see what I mean. Whats confusing me about the problem is that the left arrow has no problems at all and uses the same code. I'm using google chrome to view my work.

Not sure this is a problem for stackoverflow helps with but I can't think of anywhere else to ask. Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

This happens because double-click actually selects something (as when you double-click a word in text, it gets selected)... add these css sttributes to your `#imageWrap` div to prevent selection in your popup:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: why does it not happen when I  click the left arrow though. That is what confused me about solving it

Comment: I don't know how exactly a double-click selection works over html objects :)

Comment: Glad it helped. You should click the tick if this was the answer you were looking for. :)